# Erro em contar números de dados de uma tabela usando JOIN no laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Estou a fazer uma query em que vai listar utilizadores com dados de várias tabelas por isso estou a usar `JOIN`.

Já consegui listar os dados do utilizador, o que estou a tentar fazer agora é contar o número de players que pertencem aquele utilizador que estou a listar. 
Já fiz todo mas está me apresentando um erro que não sei como resolver.

Conto com a vossa ajuda.

**Erro**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::group_by()

**Codigo**

```
class ListaAgentesController extends Controller{

    public function lista_agentes (){

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $lista_agentes = DB::table('agents')->join('agent_types', 'agent_types.id', '=', 'agents.type')
                                            ->join('players', 'players.agent', '=', 'agents.id')
                                            ->where('agents.id', '!=', $user_id)
                                            ->select('agents.*', 'agent_types.*', 'players.*', 'agents.id as user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(players.id) as count_palyers'))                                         
                                            ->group_by('players.id')
                                            ->get();

        return view('admin.templates.agentes', ['lista_agentes' => $lista_agentes]);

    } 

}
```

Comment: Não é `group_by` e sim `groupBy`.

Comment: Resolveu o erro mas agora deixou de me listar os utilizadores

Comment: Daí já é problema na sua consulta. Você já tentou rodar essa consulta no seu SGBD ?

Comment: Não, nao pode ver pelo meu codigo se estou a fazer alguma coisa errada ?

Comment: Comentei errado. Então, não conheço a estrutura da sua tabela para te dizer o que pode estar errado. Também não sei os dados que precisam ser mostrados. Você deveria ver isto.

Comment: Pegue essa consulta e rode em seu SGBD.

Comment: Como e que eu vou rodar isto no mysql se isto e laravel

Comment: Está falando sério ? Converte isso em uma consulta para MySql !

Comment: Não esta a retornar nada no mysql nao sei o que pode estar errada ajude-me

Answer (score 1):

O `group_by` não existe no Laravel 5.3, o correto é `groupBy`, veja a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping

Assim:

```
$lista_agentes = DB::table('agents')->join('agent_types', 'agent_types.id', '=', 'agents.type')
                                    ->join('players', 'players.agent', '=', 'agents.id')
                                    ->where('agents.id', '!=', $user_id)
                                    ->select('agents.*', 'agent_types.*', 'players.*', 'agents.id as user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(players.id) as count_palyers'))                                         
                                    ->groupBy('players.id')
                                    ->get();

 return view('admin.templates.agentes', ['lista_agentes' => $lista_agentes]);
```

Para depurar a query pode tentar o [*toSql*](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) e [*getBindings*](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getBindings), como por exemplo (fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289496/1518921):

```
$builder = DB::table('agents')->join('agent_types', 'agent_types.id', '=', 'agents.type')
                                    ->join('players', 'players.agent', '=', 'agents.id')
                                    ->where('agents.id', '!=', $user_id)
                                    ->select('agents.*', 'agent_types.*', 'players.*', 'agents.id as user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(players.id) as count_palyers'))                                         
                                    ->groupBy('players.id');


$lista_agentes = $builder->get();

$sql = $builder->toSql();
$bindings = $builder->getBindings();

foreach ($bindings as $replace){
    $pos = strpos($sql, '?');

    if ($pos !== false) {
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, $replace, $pos, 1);
    }
}

dd($sql); //Extrai o conteudo da query

return view('admin.templates.agentes', ['lista_agentes' => $lista_agentes]);
```

Comment: Sim isso ja resolveu o erro mas agora o problema e que deixou de me listar os utilizadores nao me lista nada alguma coisa deve faltar na query

Comment: Mosta isto no ecra []

Comment: Em ordem chamou como assim nao percebi a sua pergunta

Comment: executei no fim do DB::table

Comment: Já deu falta aqui um ponto e virgula queres o resultado ?

Comment: Tens neste link o resultado que deu http://pastebin.com/XnEKwfeM

Comment: Da Undefined variable: model

Comment: Testei no phpmyadmin ele não retorna nenhum dado mas esta a ir buscar todas as tabelas dos joins

Comment: Eu se tirar o join dos players ele lista-me o utilizadores conforme eu quero so quando o acrescentei para fazer o count e que deixou de listar

Comment: Eu quero dentro do que já tenho feito pois acredito que alguma coisa esteja faltando na query e quero com laravel. queres que eu monte a query sem laravel e poste aqui ?

Comment: Fiz no mysql a query sem laravel mas se usar o join players nao retorna nada se o tirar retorna os dados dos utilizadores certinho uma coisa sera porque a tabela players esta vazia ?

Comment: @CésarSousa sim, se uma das tabelas estiver vazia não retorna nada, já que o `INNER JOIN` depende disto, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/3635 ... Agora o que eu não entendo, como é que antes estava retornando algo? É bem provavel que você modificou algo sem muita atenção.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52451/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-erro-em-contar-numeros-de-dados-de)

Comment: Mas a tabela pode estar vazia pois pode nao haver players registados associados aquele utilizador o quero e retornar o numero de jogadores que cada utilizador tem seja 0 ou se tiver retorna o numero deles